FFI: Safety of Send for interior mutable C API
I'm wrapping a C API for Rust usage. Below are MRE of both code
C:
static int connection;
int connect(void) {
  …
  connection = …;
  …
}

int send_msg(char const* str, int len) {
  // uses connection
  …
}

Rust:
struct Wrapper(PhantomData<*mut ()>); // marker for !Sync/!Send

impl Wrapper {
  fn connect() -> Result<Self, Error> { let ret = unsafe { ffi::connect() }; …; Self(PhantomData) }
  fn send_msg(&mut self, msg: &str) -> …
}

Now, my question is, can Wrapper implement Send? I feel like technically it would be possible to pass them between threads, provided that a fence happens before access by the other thread. I don't think there's any guarantee that such a fence happens though, which means that the API wouldn't qualify. If it indeed is !Send, does a standard wrapper exist to ensure fences happen which would make wrapper Send?

There is nothing preventing thread A from calling Wrapper::connect(), executing connect(void) for some time, get unscheduled by the OS, and some other thread B also calling connect(void) while A is sleeping. It depends on connect(void) if this is a problem. This signature of connect(void) suggests that it should be wrapped in a std::sync::Once or such.

That's a good point, thanks! I'll wrap it to make sure it's a singleton

I think the answer to this question depends on what send_msg does, which we can't see.
